# Merge MKV video and MKA audio tracks while keeping subtitles

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, matroska

I have this situation:

- file1.mkv (video with two 5.1 tracks and several subtitles)
- file1.mka (two stereo audio tracks)

I want to merge the files to a single output that has:

- 4 audio tracks (the 5.1 original tracks and the other two from the
  MKA file)
- the subtitles from the MKV

Here's the command I'm trying:

```
@ffmpeg.exe -i "file1.mkv" -i "file1.mka" -map 1 -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy "output.mkv"
```

The problem is that output.mkv does indeed have everything, but the tracks from the MKA are mute, and some players even crash when I try to play them. The other two tracks (from original MKV) work just fine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does ffprobe show any streams as disabled?

Comment: @Mulvya I'm not sure, here's the full ffprobe output: https://pastebin.com/4LxmSk4j

Comment: @Mulvya I know it sounds weird, but I think it's somehow related to subtitles. If I exclude them by manually selecting only video and audio (`-map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a copy`) it generated an output with all 4 tracks working ( [log](https://pastebin.com/FYjDYCjx) ). If I try to map subtitles too (`-map 0:v -map 0:s? -map 0:a -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy`) it generates again two broken tracks.

Answer (score 0):

why not use mkvmerge? https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html

```
 mkvmerge.exe --output E:\output.mkv --audio-tracks 1,2 --subtitle-tracks 3,4 
 --no-chapters --language 0:und --default-track 0:yes --compression 0:none    
 --language 1:und --default-track 1:yes --compression 1:none --language 2:und 
 --compression 2:none --language 3:und --compression 3:none --language 4:und  
 --default-track 4:yes --compression 4:none "E:\file1.mkv" --language 0:eng   
 --compression 0:none --language 1:und --compression 1:none "E:\file2.mka"    
 --track-order 0:0,0:1,0:2,0:3,0:4,1:0,1:1 --probe-range-percentage 0.50
```